# Ubuntu 20.04 setting path variable to solve laravel: command not found

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables, bashrc

I was following this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26376516/laravel-php-command-not-found) and noticed that it's temporarily working for me. I tried doing

`export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin" >> ~/.bashrc`

and

`export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin" >> ~/.profile`

than I did `source ~/.bashrc` and `source ~/.profile` to update those files. When I open them in an editor I don't see the new path in either file. However, I'm able to use the laravel command in that instance of terminal where I used those commands, but it doesn't work in any new terminals. How can I make this change to my `$PATH` permanent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`>>` redirects standard output. The command `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin"` doesn't produce any standard output, so nothing gets appended to the file(s).

You probably wanted

```
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

or just

```
echo 'PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

since `PATH` has almost certainly been exported into the environment already.

*Also not that the `source` command does not "update [those] files"; it updates your current shell based on the contents of those files.*

Comment: what's the diff between using ``export PATH`` and just ``PATH``?

Comment: @Pachuca `export VAR` places `VAR` (and its value) into the environment of any child processes started by the shell, whereas unexported variables only exist in the current shell environment. In the case of `PATH`, it's likely already been marked for export early in the session via `pam_env` and doesn't really need to be `export`ed again.